# Is there a way to enable on-move between Disclousre?

Tags: list, swiftui, hierarchical-data

Below is the example code and video that I wrote.

Disclousre is represented in a hierarchical structure.

Disclousre was used to use the isExpanded feature.

Do I have to customize onDrag, onDrop?

I'd appreciate your help!

[onMove gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bokgI.gif)

```swift
struct Item: Identifiable {
    var id: UUID = UUID()
    var name: String
    var children: [Item]?
    
    init(name: String, children: [Item]? ) {
        self.name = name
        self.children = children
    }
}

struct ContentView : View {
    let items: [Item] = dummy
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            RecursiveView(items: dummy)
            EditButton()
        }
    }
}

let dummy = [Item(name: "1", children: [
                    Item(name: "1-1", children: nil),
                    Item(name: "1-2", children: nil),
                    Item(name: "1-3", children: nil)]),
             Item(name: "2", children: [
                    Item(name: "2-1", children: nil),
                    Item(name: "2-2", children: nil),
                    Item(name: "2-3", children: nil)])]

struct RecursiveView: View {
    var items: [Item]?
    
    var body: some View {
        if let items = items {
            ForEach(items) { item in
                DisclosureGroup(
                    isExpanded: .constant(true),
                    content: {
                        RecursiveView(items: item.children)
                    },
                    label: {
                        Text(item.name)
                    }
                )
            }
            .onMove(perform: { indices, newOffset in
                print(indices)
                print(newOffset)
            })
        }
    }
}
```